# How to project a new point to PCA new basis?

Tags: matlab, pca, coordinate-transformation, bsxfun

For example, I have 9 variables and 362 cases. I've made PCA calculation, and found out that first 3 PCA coordinates are enough for me.

Now, I have new point in my 9-dimensional structure, and I want to project it to principal component system coordinate. How to get its new coordinates?

```
%# here is data (362x9)
load SomeData

[W, Y] = pca(data, 'VariableWeights', 'variance', 'Centered', true);

%# orthonormal coefficient matrix
W = diag(std(data))\W;

% Getting mean and weights of data (for future data)
[data, mu, sigma] = zscore(data);
sigma(sigma==0) = 1;

%# New point in original 9dim system
%# For example, it is the first point of our input data
x = data(1,:);
x = bsxfun(@minus,x, mu);
x = bsxfun(@rdivide, x, sigma);

%# New coordinates as principal components
y0 = Y(1,:); %# point we should get in result
y = (W*x')'; %# our result

%# error
sum(abs(y0 - y)) %# 142 => they are not the same point

%# plot
figure()
plot(y0,'g'); hold on;
plot(y,'r');
```

[image]

How to get coordinates of a new point projected to new principal component basis?

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the `pca()` function? Normally in matlab I use `princomp()`.

Comment: Are `Y(1,:)` and `y` in the same direction?

Comment: Now, I'm trying in a new version of Matlab. There function `princomp()` is routed to `pca()`. Ok, I'll try in older versions, all the more so I need it to work in old Matlab

Comment: @Isaac, yes, both `Y(1,:)` and `y` are `1x9`.

Comment: Direction, not dimension. Is `Y(1,:)` approximately a multiple of `y`?

Comment: @Isaac, sorry, misunderstood. I've updated my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main fallacy was in operation that converts points to new basis:

```
y = (W*x')';
```

Wikipedia says:

> The projected vectors are the columns of the matrix
>
> ```
> Y = W*·Z,
> ```
>
> where `Y is L×N, W is M×L, Z is M×N`,

but `pca()` returns `W` of size `L×M` and `Y` of size `NxL`

so, correct equation in Matlab is:

```
y = x*W
```

Below is the corrected code:

```
[W, Y] = pca(data, 'VariableWeights', 'variance', 'Centered', true);
W = diag(std(data))\W;

%# Getting mean and weights of data (for future data)
[~, mu, we] = zscore(data);
we(we==0) = 1;

%# New point in original 9dim system
%# For example, it is the first point of our input data
x = data(1,:); 
x = bsxfun(@minus,x, mu);
x = bsxfun(@rdivide, x, we);

%# New coordinates as principal components
y = x*W;
y0 = Y(1,:);
sum(abs(y0 - y)) %# 4.1883e-14 ~= 0
```