# Is there a way to project new sample points onto already calculated PCA basis?

Tags: scikit-learn

There is exactly the same question, but it is for Matlab:

[How to project a new point to PCA new basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303300/how-to-project-a-new-point-to-pca-new-basis)

Can the same thing be done in sklearn?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [the `transform` method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform) on your `PCA` object.

Comment: Ok! That was incredibly easy, after all.  Thanks.